# TFLite converter not replacing dummy_function with TFLite_Detection_PostProcess

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-serving, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I want to implement a `tf.Module` for decoding box predictions and applying NonMaxSuppression that is convertible to tflite.

This implementation includes elements from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/modeling/layers/detection_generator.py#L792).

It also follows [this guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/models/convert/operation_fusion.md) on operation fusion.

This is my Code:

```py
def decode_predictions_lite(anchor_boxes: tf.Tensor, box_pred: tf.Tensor, cls_pred: tf.Tensor, variance: tf.Tensor, image_shape):
    """a concrete function that decodes box and class predictions and applies NonMaxSuppression

    Args:
        anchor_boxes: tf.Tensor of shape [1, N, 4] representing anchor_boxes in the 'center_yxhw' format
        box_pred: tf.Tensor of shape [b, N, 4] representing encoded box predictions from the model's output
        cls_pred: tf.Tensor of shape [b, N, num_classes] representing the class logits from the model's output
        variance: tf.Tensor of shape [4] representing the box variance that was used when encoding the boxes
        image_shape: tf.Tensor of shape [2] representing the height and width of the input image
    Returns: 
        pass
    Note: 
        - N is the number of anchor boxes. All input tensors are of dtype float32
        - b is the batch_size. For now, only a batch_size of 1 is supported.
    """
    scores = tf.sigmoid(cls_pred)
    boxes = box_pred*variance
    decoded_boxes = tf.concat(
        [
            boxes[..., :2] * anchor_boxes[..., :2] + anchor_boxes[..., :2],
            tf.math.exp(boxes[..., :2]) * anchor_boxes[..., :2]
        ], axis=-1
    )
    
    # Normalize anchor coordinates for TFLite's NMS operation.
    normalize_factor = tf.tile(image_shape, [2])
    anchor_boxes = anchor_boxes / normalize_factor
    anchor_boxes = tf.squeeze(anchor_boxes) # squeeze so the anchor_boxes are of shape (N, 4)
    
    # normalize box coordinates for TFLite's NMS operation
    decoded_boxes_rel = decoded_boxes / normalize_factor

    def get_implements_signature():
        implements_signature = ' '.join([
        'name: "%s"' % 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess',
        'attr { key: "max_detections" value { i: %d } }' % 100,
        'attr { key: "max_classes_per_detection" value { i: %d } }' % 1,
        'attr { key: "detections_per_class" value { i: %d } }' % 5,
        'attr { key: "use_regular_nms" value { b: %s } }' % "false", # Lower
        'attr { key: "nms_score_threshold" value { f: %f } }' % 0.1,
        'attr { key: "nms_iou_threshold" value { f: %f } }' % 0.5,
        'attr { key: "y_scale" value { f: %f } }' % 1.0,
        'attr { key: "x_scale" value { f: %f } }' % 1.0,
        'attr { key: "h_scale" value { f: %f } }' % 1.0,
        'attr { key: "w_scale" value { f: %f } }' % 1.0,
        'attr { key: "num_classes" value { i: %d } }' % num_classes,
        ])
        return implements_signature
    
    @tf.function(experimental_implements=get_implements_signature())
    def dummy_postprocessing_nms(input_boxes, input_scores, input_anchors):
        boxes = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='boxes')
        scores = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='scores')
        classes = tf.constant(0.0, shape=(1, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='classes')
        num_detections = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='num_detections')
        return boxes, classes, scores, num_detections
    
    return decoded_boxes, dummy_postprocessing_nms(decoded_boxes_rel, scores, anchor_boxes)

class PredictionDecoderLite(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PredictionDecoderLite, self).__init__()
    
    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, 4], dtype=tf.float32),  # anchor_boxes
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, 4], dtype=tf.float32),  # box_pred
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, None], dtype=tf.float32),  # cls_pred
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[4], dtype=tf.float32),  # variance
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32)   # image_shape
    ])
    def decode_preds_lite(self, anchor_boxes, box_pred, cls_pred, variance, image_shape):
        return decode_predictions_lite(anchor_boxes, box_pred, cls_pred, variance, image_shape)
    
decoder_module = PredictionDecoderLite()
concrete_fn_with_nms = decoder_module.decode_preds_lite.get_concrete_function()

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_fn_with_nms], trackable_obj=decoder_module)

tflite_pred_decoder = converter.convert()
with open(tflite_postprocess_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_pred_decoder)
```

The issue is that the converter does not rewrites the dummy function to TFLite's custom NMS operation. I tested the tflite module with the following code:

```py
image_shape = [HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3]
variance = tf.constant([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

anchor_generator = kcv.models.RetinaNet.default_anchor_generator(bounding_box_format)
anchors = anchor_generator(image_shape=image_shape)
anchors = ops.concatenate([a for a in anchors.values()], axis=0)
anchors = tf.expand_dims(anchors, axis=0)
print("anchors: ", anchors.shape)   # anchors:  (1, 76725, 4)
print("boxes: ", predictions['box'].shape)  # boxes:  (1, 76725, 4)
print("scores: ", predictions['classification'].shape)  # scores:  (1, 76725, 4)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(tflite_postprocess_path)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], anchors.shape)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[1]['index'], predictions['box'].shape)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[2]['index'], predictions['classification'].shape)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], anchors.numpy())
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], predictions['box'])
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], predictions['classification'])
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[3]['index'], variance.numpy())
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[4]['index'], np.array(image_shape[:2], dtype='float32'))
interpreter.invoke()

# Retrieve outputs:
decoded_boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
final_boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
final_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])
final_classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])
num_detections = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[4]['index'])
```

I received zeros from my dummy function and no post-processed boxes.
I don't know how to get more information out of the converter to see, what is wrong.
Does anyone have an idea, how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

So...
After almost two days of debugging, I finally found a workaround.
Instead of using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions()` we first save the module and then use `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()`.
In the tensorflow model garden, they do it the same way ([See here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/854febef7f028d9a0304901a78b1a81d773459c7/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_lib_tf2.py#L371C3-L371C3)).

There were also some other issues in the code above so here is an updated version. You can directly use the box and class predictions from a `keras_cv.models.RetinaNet` that was converted to tflite.

```py
class PredictionDecoderLite(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, box_variance):
        self._num_classes = num_classes
        self._box_variance = box_variance
        super(PredictionDecoderLite, self).__init__()
        
        self.decode_preds_lite = tf.function(
            input_signature=[
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32),  # anchor_boxes
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, 4], dtype=tf.float32),  # box_pred
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, self._num_classes], dtype=tf.float32),  # cls_pred
            ]
        )(self._decode_preds_impl)
    
    def _decode_preds_impl(self, anchor_boxes, box_pred, cls_pred):
        """a concrete function that decodes box and class predictions and applies NonMaxSuppression

        Args:
            anchor_boxes: tf.Tensor of shape [N, 4] representing anchor_boxes in the 'center_yxhw' format
            box_pred: tf.Tensor of shape [b, N, 4] representing encoded box predictions from the model's output
            cls_pred: tf.Tensor of shape [b, N, num_classes] representing the class logits from the model's output
        Returns: 
            pass
        Note: 
            - N is the number of anchor boxes. All input tensors are of dtype float32
            - b is the batch_size. For now, only a batch_size of 1 is supported.
              See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc#L894C3-L894C17
        """
        class_predictions = tf.sigmoid(cls_pred)

        # Rename the input tensors.
        # See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8c93fe44deb850c5978229723e65b3a7130d7422/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/python/tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc#L58
        with tf.name_scope('raw_outputs'):
            box_encodings = tf.identity(box_pred, name='box_encodings')
            class_predictions = tf.identity(class_predictions, name='class_predictions')
        anchor_boxes = tf.identity(anchor_boxes, name='anchors') # Rename anchor_boxes to match TFLite's custom NMS    

        # See: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_lib_tf2.py#L188
        def get_implements_signature():
            implements_signature = ' '.join([
            'name: "%s"' % 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess',
            'attr { key: "max_detections" value { i: %d } }' % 100,
            'attr { key: "max_classes_per_detection" value { i: %d } }' % 1,
            'attr { key: "detections_per_class" value { i: %d } }' % 5,
            'attr { key: "use_regular_nms" value { b: %s } }' % "false",
            'attr { key: "nms_score_threshold" value { f: %f } }' % 0.1,
            'attr { key: "nms_iou_threshold" value { f: %f } }' % 0.5,
            'attr { key: "y_scale" value { f: %f } }' % (1.0/self._box_variance[0]),
            'attr { key: "x_scale" value { f: %f } }' % (1.0/self._box_variance[1]),
            'attr { key: "h_scale" value { f: %f } }' % (1.0/self._box_variance[2]),
            'attr { key: "w_scale" value { f: %f } }' % (1.0/self._box_variance[3]),
            'attr { key: "num_classes" value { i: %d } }' % cls_pred.shape[-1],
            ])
            return implements_signature
        
        @tf.function(experimental_implements=get_implements_signature())
        def dummy_postprocessing_nms(input_boxes, input_scores, input_anchors):
            boxes = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='boxes')
            scores = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='scores')
            classes = tf.constant(0.0, shape=(1, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='classes')
            num_detections = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32, name='num_detections')
            return boxes, classes, scores, num_detections
        return dummy_postprocessing_nms(box_encodings, class_predictions, anchor_boxes)[::-1]
    
decoder_module = PredictionDecoderLite(
    num_classes=num_classes, 
    box_variance=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
)
concrete_fn_with_nms = decoder_module.decode_preds_lite.get_concrete_function()

# Export SavedModel
tf.saved_model.save(
    decoder_module,
    os.path.join(model_dir, 'detection_module'),
    signatures=concrete_fn_with_nms)

# Convert SavedModel
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(
    saved_model_dir=os.path.join(model_dir, 'detection_module'),
)
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tflite_pred_decoder = converter.convert()
with open(tflite_postprocess_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_pred_decoder)
```

We can test the module the same way as before. **Note:** the order of input and output tensors is a bit strange.

```py
image_shape = [HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3]

anchor_generator = kcv.models.RetinaNet.default_anchor_generator("center_yxhw")
anchors = anchor_generator(image_shape=image_shape)
anchors = ops.concatenate([a for a in anchors.values()], axis=0).numpy()
box_pred = predictions['box']
cls_pred = predictions['classification']

print("anchors: ", anchors.shape)   # anchors:  (76725, 4)
print("boxes: ", box_pred.shape)    # boxes:    (1, 76725, 4)
print("scores: ", cls_pred.shape)   # scores:   (1, 76725, 4)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(tflite_postprocess_path)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
signature_list = interpreter.get_signature_list()
print(input_details)
print(output_details)

interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], box_pred.shape)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[1]['index'], anchors.shape)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[2]['index'], cls_pred.shape)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], box_pred)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], anchors)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], cls_pred)
interpreter.invoke()

# # Retrieve outputs:
final_boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
final_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
final_classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])
num_detections = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])
n = int(num_detections[0])
print("final_boxes: ", final_boxes[0, :n])
print("final_scores: ", final_scores[0, :n])
print("final_classes: ", final_classes[0, :n])
print("num_detections: ", n)
```

It is worth noting that TFLite's custom NMS operation does the box-decoding for you ([See here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc#L271)).
So far I have not found any documentation about this op. It would have made thinks much easier.